# Writing a Blackjack program in Python, how to address Ace and Dealer cards?

Tags: python, blackjack, card

I'm still learning Python and have created a Blackjack program. So far I have a basic deck created, and the blackjack program itself which makes the dealer get a random hand between 17 and 26

What I'm trying to get now though is:

Make Ace count as either 1 or 11 based on the current value of the hand like an actual Ace

Make the Dealer actually draw cards, starting with 1 card

Remove a drawn card from the deck

Deck:

```
def create_deck():
    deck = {'A of spades':1,
            '2 of spades':2,
            '3 of spades':3,
            '4 of spades':4,
            '5 of spades':5,
            '6 of spades':6,
            '7 of spades':7,
            '8 of spades':8,
            '9 of spades':9,
            '10 of spades':10,
            'J of spades':10,
            'Q of spades':10,
            'K of spades':10,

            'A of hearts': 1,
            '2 of hearts': 2,
            '3 of hearts': 3,
            '4 of hearts': 4,
            '5 of hearts': 5,
            '6 of hearts': 6,
            '7 of hearts': 7,
            '8 of hearts': 8,
            '9 of hearts': 9,
            '10 of hearts': 10,
            'J of hearts': 10,
            'Q of hearts': 10,
            'K of hearts': 10,

            'A of clubs': 1,
            '2 of clubs': 2,
            '3 of clubs': 3,
            '4 of clubs': 4,
            '5 of clubs': 5,
            '6 of clubs': 6,
            '7 of clubs': 7,
            '8 of clubs': 8,
            '9 of clubs': 9,
            '10 of clubs': 10,
            'J of clubs': 10,
            'Q of clubs': 10,
            'K of clubs': 10,

            'A of diamonds': 1,
            '2 of diamonds': 2,
            '3 of diamonds': 3,
            '4 of diamonds': 4,
            '5 of diamonds': 5,
            '6 of diamonds': 6,
            '7 of diamonds': 7,
            '8 of diamonds': 8,
            '9 of diamonds': 9,
            '10 of diamonds': 10,
            'J of diamonds': 10,
            'Q of diamonds': 10,
            'K of diamonds': 10,
            }
    return deck
```

Blackjack:

```
import createdeck
import random

def main():
    current_value = 0
    deck = createdeck.create_deck()
    dealer_card = random.randint(17,26)
    print('Dealer finished drawing')
    draw_card = input('Hit? y for yes: ')
    while draw_card == 'y' or draw_card == 'Y':
        result = deal_cards(deck, current_value)
        draw_card = result[1]
        current_value = result[0]

    print(f"Dealer's hand is {dealer_card}")
    if current_value > 21:
        print('You bust. You lost the game.')
    elif dealer_card > 21:
        print('Dealer bust. You win!')
    elif dealer_card <= 21 and dealer_card < current_value:
        print('Congratulations! You win!')
    else:
        print('Sorry, you lost the game')

def deal_cards(deck, c_value):

    keys = list(deck.keys())
    card = random.choice(keys)
    value = deck[card]
    random.shuffle(keys)
    print(card)
    c_value += value
    print('Current value in hand:', c_value)

    if c_value < 21:
        d_card = input('Hit? Press y to hit. Press other key to stand: ')
    else:
        d_card = 0
    return c_value, d_card

main()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is too vague. What exactly do you need help with? What is the problem?

Comment: Problem is I currently only have Ace defaulted to 1 and the dealer just gets a random number between 17 and 26. Trying to put in Ace = 1 or 11 simply gives me an error

What I need help with is making Ace count as either 1 OR 11 based on the current hand value, AND I need to make the dealer draw cards instead of simply start with a hand between the predetermined values

Comment: I think you've realised the short-comings of using a dictionary with fixed scores. You could define a `hand_score()` function which will treat Aces as 11 unless that would cause a bust and otherwise as 1. That would mean tracking the cards in the hand, rather than the score. Also whenever a card is *dealt*, you're creating a new deck and I'm not sure if that is intentional.

Answer (score 0):

just keep track of the number of aces and then you can decrement the score after (i usually default aces to 11)

```
def calc_score(cards):
    ttl = 0
    num_aces = 0
    for c in  cards:
        ttl += deck[c]
        if c.startswith("ace"):
           ttl += 10
           num_aces += 1
    while aces and ttl > 21:
        ttl -= 10
        num_aces -= 1
    return ttl

calc_score(['ace of hearts', 'ace of diamonds', '5 of hearts','4 of hearts'])
```